# Trying to understand crash log output

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I'm trying to understand debug output from a crash log. I have the following line from the crashlog:

```
22  FG                          0x00022b94 0x1000 + 138132
```

I understand how to use atos on 0x00022b94 to get the source code location.

What I would like to know is why the crash log helpfully splits that number into  0x1000 + 138132? I have googled and the googles failed me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0x1000 is where the __TEXT segment of that binary file (your app or some dylib) is mapped to, and 138132
 is the (decimal) offset from that origin. This separation allows program to find the error location in a position-independent way.

Comment: So what am I supposed to do with 138132?

Comment: @John: Not much if you're not willing to dig into assembly. But you could use `symbolicatecrash` to let the computer to figure it out for you.